# Task and plugin conflict in Gradle (Failed to apply plugin [class 'org.gradle.langu...)

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-task

I tried to run a task from `build.gradle` using the following command:

```
gradle footype
```

However the build failed and displayed these two error messages that I want to fix:

```
> Configure project : 
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to 
be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
```

And this message as well:

```
* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'java']
> Failed to apply plugin [class         
'org.gradle.language.base.plugins.LifecycleBasePlugin']
   > Declaring custom 'assemble' task when using the standard Gradle 
lifecycle plugins is not allowed.
```

Here is the code of the `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins{
  id "com.gradle.build-scan" version "1.10.2"
  id "org.arquillian.spacelift" version "1.0.0-alpha-17"
  id "java"
}

group 'k'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

task fooType {
  doLast {
    def foo = "bar"
    println "$foo + foo = ${foo + "foo"}"
  }
}
```

I searched on other posts and they all seem to mention a task called clean() which doesn't appear in my code, so I'd like to know what's the problem.

Thank you muchly for reading this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to this message:

> Configure project : 
>   The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to 
>   be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.

it is just a warning. It states that one (possibly more) plugin you applied uses `<<` which will be removed in version 5.0 of gradle in favour of `doLast`. You are not using `<<` directly in your script and that's ok. To eliminate this warning first of all you need to know which plugin uses it, then raise an issue on plugin's site asking for deprecated code elimination.

When it comes to the second message it's an error and in single build script nothing can be done about it. Two plugins `java` and `org.arquillian.spacelift` have declared a task with the same name (it's `assemble`) - this is a conflict. Maybe you can split you project into a multimodule?

Comment: oh, I see:D thanks a lot. I'll just delete org.arquillian.spacelift, I don't need it for the moment. Thank you sooooo muuuuch.

Comment: @AbdelghaniBekka, if you found my answer useful, please accept it :) See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) how it works.

Comment: Done, I didn't know about that option. Your answer was useful plenty:)